# What permissions should I request to display a modal on a specific list of websites and have a short approval delay

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm working on an extension that injects some html code (display a modal) on a specific list of partner websites.
Because this list grows everyday, my extension fetch an external json file and compare it with the current website. If one of them matches, I show the modal.

I'm currently asking for a `*://*/*` permission for content_scripts.
I tried to set the list of websites in the manifest, but for each new version it needed the user to reactivate the extension as it required "new permissions".

Here is an extract of my current manifest.json

```
{
  "permissions":["*://*/*","activeTab","storage","<all_urls>"],
  ...
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "run_at": "document_idle",
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "css": ["..."],
      "js": ["..."]
    }
  ],
  ...
  "externally_connectable": {
    "matches": [
      "*://localhost/*",
      "*://*.mywebsite.com/*"
    ]
  }
}
```

What would be the best permissions configuration to shorten the approval process? Currently each time I submit a new version it takes several days to be approved, even for small changes.

Comment: Use [declarativeContent](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent) API with [optional permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/permissions#manifest) or switch to programmatic injection using chrome.tabs.onUpdated (or chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted) and chrome.tabs.executeScript.

Comment: thanks @wOxxOm I'll give it a try today and tell you if it works.